# Keyboard shortcut for the RUN button when using VS Code with Java?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

I use VS Code with the Extension Pack for Java.

When I am in a Java project I have a RUN button at the top right of the window:

[image: Run Button in VS Code]

I could not find a keyboard short cut or an entry in the "Show All Commands" list for it.

Is there a way to activate this Java RUN button with a keyboard shortcut? (I'm happy to set up my own shortcut if needed.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Follow the steps below to set shortcut keys:**

1. Click the *gear icon* in the lower left corner of the interface
2. Select **Keyboard Shortcuts** *(Ctrl + K + S)*

   [image]
3. Search **run java**

   [image]
4. Double click **Run Java**
5. Press the shortcut key you want to bind

   [image]

**Now you can run Java programs using the shortcut keys you just bound.**

Comment: Good to know tbat there is a *Run Java* action - only strange that it does not show up on the command list (Ctrl-shift-P).